# High resolution PNG image won't display

Tags: java, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I encountered a problem with uploading an image.

It seems that i can't display PNG images that exceeds 2800x2800 pixel after upload.
But I can display jpeg images that exceeds those resolutions.

Is there a way to modify the maximum resolution for png images? 
Or is there a way to prevent uploading a high resolution png image?
I'm using `file.browse()` to upload image.

Answer (score 1):

see [Flash Player 10 size limits for SWF, bitmap files](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/size-limits-swf-bitmap-files.html):

> To access the increased bitmap size limits, it's required that the
>   compiled is SWF version 10 or later. Content compiled to a SWF 9
>   target and running in Flash Player 10 or later are still subject to
>   Flash Player 9 limits (2880 x 2880 pixels). The largest square bitmap
>   allowed is 4,095 x 4,095 pixels. ...